# How to understand this sentence of matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
plt.text(60, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$')
```

I can undertand the position, but the r string seems unfamiliar to me.

1. what does two $ mean? Is it relative to print μ and σ ?
2. \ \ in the sentence seems no meaning for two \
3. And is it a special grammar in matplotlib or a feature I don't know in Python?

Comment: `r'something'` is [perfectly regular Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part you did not understand is not actually Python, it's a feature of Matplotlib meant for including symbols and equations in your plots. It is called  [**math text**](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) , which is like math mode in  [**LaTex**](https://www.latex-project.org/) .

1. The `$` signs are symbols indicating a math block. What they do here is convert the \mu into a `μ` and \sigma into a `σ`
2. The first `\` marks the space as a character, so that it does not disappear in the rendered text.
3. The `r' '` string is a raw Python string. This means that all characters are literal, which means no escaping is necessary (and the backslashes don't act like escape characters).

Comment: On your #2: spaces in *math mode* (as indicated by the `$`) always disappear. Hence the backslash here – it's unnecessary outside math mode.

Comment: There is actually a difference between [using LaTeX](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#usetex-tutorial) in matplotlib and what you see here, which is often called MathText, see [Writing mathematical expressions](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html). There is a big overlap between the two, so usually you would not see any difference.